# How to cache-control multiple resource locations in Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching

We are using the WebContentInterceptor to prevent caching on dynamic resources but have not been able to add caching headers to static resources in multiple locations.

The main issue is static content (glyphicons) coming from dependency jars (bootstrap) are given no-cache headers, resulting in the glyphicons disappearing if the browser (IE 11.. corporate environment) is refreshed.

```
// servlet-context.xml

<mvc:annotation-driven ... />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="3600" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

... 

<mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/resources/**" />
    <bean id="noCacheWebContentInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

This works in adding a cache-period to the static resources in /resources/ and no-cache for everything else, I just need to add a cache-period to the jar dependencies. I have tried different resource mappings such as:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/, /webjars/" cache-period="3600" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/" cache-period="3600" />
```

Have also tried creating additional separate resource mappings and adding another mvc:exclude-mapping path to the interceptor without success. I'm not sure if I'm not getting the correct path for these dependency jars, or if its even possible to map those locations, or if I'm simply doing something else wrong.